# What is the mistake in the follow expression "he looked several things"?

Tags: meaning, grammar

I want to know what is the mistake in that expression, I think the mistake is the missing of the connector after the verb "looked" but I'm not sure

Comment: Hi Elias. We have a specific site called [ell.se] which is for people learning the English language. You might find better answers there.

Comment: thank you @DJClayworth I'll take a look

Comment: Actually, it could be valid in some contexts:  He looked several things: dazed, confused, and disoriented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the verbal phrase *"He looked at several things"*.  Here "looked at" is considered transitive.  Without the preposition, a similar sentence could be:

*"He saw several things"*

Also transitive and also past tense.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @Gary's Student